# Can't get selenium python to click the submit button on google maps

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

Can't get selenium python to click the submit button on google maps. I have been able to make it input text into the google maps search bar but that's it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps/")

inputboxes = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'text_field')
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'searchboxinput').send_keys("byu store")

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    driver.find_element((By.ID, "searchbox-searchbutton"))
)
element.click()
```

This part doesn't work.

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    driver.find_element((By.ID, "searchbox-searchbutton"))
)
element.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following to click the search button.

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "searchbox-searchbutton")))
element.click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Your previous code had a

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'using' must be a string
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be submitting.

Comment: Ok yeah your right I imported the only one of the two things you suggested. Now it works. Thanks for your help!